# Use a field or a whole new table?

Tags: database, database-design, invoice

I could really use some insights on choosing between the following two database layouts.

```
Layout #1          | Layout #2  
                   |  
CUSTOMERS          | CUSTOMERS  
 id int pk         |  id int pk  
 info char         |  info char  
                   |  
ORDERS             | ORDERS  
 id int pk         |  id int pk  
 customerid int fk |  customerid int fk  
 date timedate     |  date timedate  
                   |  
DETAILS            | INVOICES  
 id int pk         |  id int pk  
 orderid int fk    |  orderid int fk  
 date timedate     |  date timedate  
 description char  |  
 amount real       | DETAILS  
 period int        |  id int pk  
                   |  invoiceid int fk  
                   |  date timedate  
                   |  description char  
                   |  amount real
```

This is a billing application for a small business, a sole proprietor. The first layout has no separate table for invoices, relying instead on the field 'period' in DETAILS for the billing cycle number. The second layout introduces a table specifically for invoices.

Specifically in this application, at what point do you see Layout #1 breaking, or what kind of things will get harder and harder as the amount of data increases? In the case of Layout #2, what does the added flexibility/complexity mean in practical terms? What are the implications for 30-60-90 aging? I'm sure that will be necessary at some point.

More generally, this seems to be a general case of whether you track/control something through a field in a table or a whole new table, yet it's not really a normalization issue, is it? How do you generally make the choice?

Comment: I think you'd serve your client best by suggesting they buy a copy of Quickbooks instead of writing a database application for them.

Comment: @Catcall Thanks, but it's just a practice application. There's no client. I've read some of your posts, and you seem to know your stuff. I'd appreciate your thoughts on the programming issue if you can spare them. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the previous comments, this is how I would approach it:

```
CUSTOMERS
  id int pk
  info char

CASES
  id int pk
  customerid int fk
  dateOpened datetime
  dateClosed datetime
  status int <- open, closed, final billed, etc.
  BillPeriod int <- here is where you determine how often to bill the client.
  BillStartDate datetime <- date that billings should start on.

BILLING
  billingid int pk
  caseid int fk
  userid int fk <- id of person who is charging to this case. i.e. the lawyer.
  invoicedetailid fk <- nullable, this will make it easier to determine if this particular item has been invoiced or not.
  amount money
  billdate datetime
  billingcode int fk <- associate with some type of billing code table so you know what this is: time, materials, etc.
  description char


INVOICES
  invoiceid int pk
  customerid int FK
  invoicedate datetime
  amount money <- sum of all invoice details
  status int <- paid, unpaid, collection, etc..
  discount money <- sum of all invoice details discounts
  invoicetotal <- usually amount - discount.

INVOICEDETAILS
  invoicedetailid int PK
  invoiceid int FK
  billingid int FK
  discount money <- amount of a discount, if any
```

===========

In the above you open a "case" and associate it with a customer.  On an ongoing basis one or more people apply Billings to the case.

Once the combination of the bill start date and period have elapsed, then the system will create a new Invoice with Details copied from the Billing table.  It should do this based on those details that have not already been billed.  You should lock the billing record from future changes once it has been invoiced.

You might have to change "BillPeriod" to some other type of field if you need different triggers.  For example, period is just one "trigger" to create an invoice.

One might include sending an invoice when you hit a certain dollar amount.  This could be configured at the customer or case level.  Another option is capping expenditures.  For example putting a cap value at the case level which would prevent billings from going over the cap; or at the very least causing an alert to be sent to the relevant parties.

Comment: Thanks, Chris, and my apologies for the late acceptance. Great answer!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure why "period" is attached to the item instead of the order itself.  Layout #1 seems to imply that you can have an open "order" that is made up of "details" which might be added and paid for over a period of years.  This seems very wrong and should make accounting a nightmare.  Layout #2 really isn't much better.

Generally speaking an Order is comprised of a single transaction with a purchase or contract date.  That transaction might encompass multiple detail items, but it's still one transaction.  It represents a single agreement made at a certain point in time between the buyer and seller.  If new items are purchased, a new order is created...  With this in mind, neither table structure works.

Regarding Invoices.  An order might have one or more invoices attached to it.  The goal of invoices is to have payments applied against them.  For small transactions there is a one-to-one relationship between invoices and orders.

In larger transactions, you might have multiple invoices that get applied to a single order.  For example if you have contracted to make "3 easy payments of $199.99 ..." .  In this case you would have 3 invoices for $199.99 each applied to a single order whose total was $599.97; and each due at different time periods.

An Invoice table should then have at minimum the Order Id, Invoice Number, Invoice Date, Invoiced Amount, Date Due, Transaction Id (for credit card), Check Number (obvious), Amount Received and Date Received fields.

If you want to get fancy and support more of the real world, then you would additionally have a Payments table which stored the Invoice Number, Amount Received (or refunded), Date Received, Transaction ID, and Check Number.  If you go this route, remove those fields from the Invoice table.

---

Now, if you need to support recurring charges (for example, internet hosting), then you would have a different table called "Contracts" and "ContractDetails" or something similar.  These tables would store the contract details (similar to orders and order details, but includes date start, date end, and recurring period).  When the next billing period is hit, then the details would be used to create an order and the appropriate invoices generated..

Comment: Thanks, I'll digest your answer, but let me clarify that it's not a retail type situation where six items are bought at once in a single transaction. I was trying to make the example generic, but it's legal billing, and the ORDERS are actually legal cases, which can drag on for years. Still, time and expenses are usually billed on monthly intervals even though the case is not over. The "invoice" is just for current activity, which can be extracted by using the period field or relating the detail lines directly to an invoice record.

Comment: PS I think it would be the same case for a hotel application, where guests check in and accrue charges over time. Guests who exceed their credit limits are asked to pay down their balances, but the "account" is one long chronology of charges and payments from check-in to check-out.

Comment: Really interesting answer, that was very helpful! Just a quick question, what is "Invoiced Amount" in the invoice table? Is that the total of order cost from order table? If that not the case then shouldn't the total cost of the orders be stored in the invoice table? Also in the invoice table should it include status field? like Due, Paid, UnPaid, Cancelled?

Comment: @user622378: Invoiced amount *might* be the grand total from the order table, or it might be only part of it.  This is to support multiple invoices for a single order.  And yes, the invoice table should have a status field.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing legal billing, I'd suggest you spend some time looking at the features of [Sage Timeslips](http://www.sagetimeslips.com/). Lawyers don't behave like other people; accounting software for lawywers doesn't behave like other accounting software. It's the nature of the business.

They have a 30-day free trial, and you can probably learn a lot from the help files and documentation.

Besides, reverse-engineering database design from the user interface is good practice.